# How to format date using JsonFormat

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

I want to format the data using @JsonFormat and exclude the nanosecond.

```
       [{ "createtime": "2021-02-08 16:44:41.336475",  "orderdate": "2021-02-03 22:55:54.764" }, { "createtime": "2021-02-08 16:44:41.3365",  "orderdate": "2021-02-03 22:55:54.4" }]
```

The no of digits of nanoseconds is not fixed. Below is the code I've written

```
 @JsonProperty("createtime")
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
 private LocalDateTime createTime;

@JsonProperty("orderdate")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private LocalDateTime orderDate;
```

when "createtime": "2021-02-08 15:14:41.33675", I'm getting Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime.
Please advise me how can I format the date in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your code produce right now?

Comment: edited the question, please check! if create time is 2021-02-08 16:44:41.33647 then I'm getting Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as I understood your question about deserialization from json to java LocalDateTime property. For this situation you could use something like this:

```
private class Timed {

        private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

        @JsonIgnore
        private LocalDateTime createTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        public LocalDateTime getCreateTime() {
            return createTime;
        }

        public void setCreateTime(LocalDateTime createTime) {
            this.createTime = createTime;
        }

        @JsonProperty("createtime")
        public String createTime() {
            return formatter.format(createTime);
        }

        @JsonCreator
        public void setCreateTime(@JsonProperty("createtime") String property) {
            createTime = LocalDateTime.parse(json, formatter).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Timed{" +
                    "createTime=" + createTime +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Update:
You could get rid of nanoseconds at all:

```
  private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

  @JsonCreator
  public void setCreateTime(@JsonProperty("createtime") String property){
        String withoutNanos = property.split("\\.")[0];
        createTime = LocalDateTime.parse(withoutNanos, formatter);
  }
```

Comment: will this work if no of the digits of nanoseconds changes also? I mean if createtime is 2021-02-08 16:44:41.33647 then also it will work?

Comment: Yes. You could change and use any format you want. 

     String withoutNanos = property.split("\\.")[0];
     createTime = LocalDateTime.parse(withoutNanos, formatter).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);